# Determine Stiffness of Initial Value Problem

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We're given the following IVP $$\dot{y}(t)= A y(t) + b$$ with

$ \begin{equation*}
b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
t  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}$
$ \begin{equation*}
,A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\epsilon & \epsilon^2\\
0 &  -1/\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}$
,$y(t_0)= \begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
- \sqrt{3}  \\
+ \pi  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}$, small $\epsilon > 0$,  and $t_0= \sqrt{2}$

We're asked wether this IVP is arbitrary stiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked up the definition of a stiff IVP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation#Etymology).

The realpart of the Eigenvalues of $A$ needs to be negative, and the ratio of $\frac{\max|\lambda_i|}{\min|\lambda_i|}$arbitray "large", in order to be stiff.

In our case, the eigenvalue problem $(-)(\epsilon + \lambda)\cdot (-)(1/ \epsilon + \lambda) - \epsilon^2 \cdot 0 = 0$ gives $\lambda_1 = - \epsilon, \lambda_2= - 1/\epsilon$. Because $\epsilon$ is small and $>0$, then both $-\epsilon$ and $-1/\epsilon$ are negative, and the absolute value of $-1/ \epsilon$ is much greater than the one of $- \epsilon$. Thus $\frac{\max |\lambda_i|}{\min|\lambda_i|}=\frac{ |-1/\epsilon|}{|-\epsilon|}= 1/\epsilon^2$ which is arbitary large for arbritrarily small $\epsilon$

Thus this IVP is arbitrarily stiff.

Comment: $A$ is triangular, you can directly read off the eigenvalues as the entries of the diagonal. And yes, there is a distinct fast-slow dynamic present.